# Multiple jquery droppable problems

Tags: jquery

I have two problems with multiple droppable div.

1. In the case that there are two adjacent (or overlapped) droppable div, a big draggable div may be accepted by both droppable. How to prevent this? I want to make sure one draggable div is accepted by one droppable div.

   ```
   look here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/GRWJn/1/
   ```
2. If I drag a child of one droppable div to another droppable div, how can I tell who is his previous parent?

   ```
   look here for example: http://jsfiddle.net/NE38y/
   ```

any advice? thx.

Comment: downvotes should be explained - this question doesn't deserve them without comment.

Comment: that's okay, I got used to the mental of internet users already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can prevent `#1` in this case, but you could do so if you make `drop1` a parent of `drop2` using the `greedy:true` [option](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#propagation%5d) which prevents propagation.

Regarding `#2`:

If you pass an `event` argument to your `drop` function, you can get the parent element using `event.toElement.parentElement`.

e.g.:

```
$(".dropzone").droppable({
    hoverClass: "drophover",
    greedy: true,
    drop: function(event) {
        //log parent to console.
        console.log(event.toElement.parentElement);
        $(this).html("dropped!");    
}
```